# Calling grailsApplication inside a static method

Tags: groovy

In my class i have defined,

```
def grailsApplication;
```

Now inside a static method am trying to access it and it gives an error:

```
Groovy:Apparent variable 'grailsApplication' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
```

How can i access the **grailsApplication** inside a static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass it as a method argument:

```
static someMethod( grailsApplication ){...}
```

Grails developers discourage using static tricks to access the app-context

Comment: "Grails developers discourage using static tricks to access the app-context" - The question doesn't say anything about accessing the app-context.  Is there some reason to believe that is what he/she is trying to do?

Comment: well, with the lack of information I had to use my imagination :)

Comment: I see.  There are lots of reasons folks interact with grailsApplication that don't directly involve the application context.